# getting datasource from RDL for reportviewer, C# winform

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

Can anyone tell me how to get datasource from RDL file ,and use in Reportviewer, using C# winform? Any resources,walkthrough or tutorials will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance. (Currently I only have rdl file. no XML or whatsoever and I don't wish to convert RDLC if possible because I have complicated report layout patterns ).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of C# winform you can use C# webform to get a datasource from rdl,
here Datasource is an only credential to access the database,
In the query desigenr you wants to mention the storedprocedure to get a data for data set